# Yii2: ActionColumn in GridView doesn't work when using SqlDataProvider

Tags: gridview, yii2

Why did Action Column (*view, update, delete*) in my Grid View return value **id** incremental from zero (not return id from database)?

My Controller

```php
public function actionIndex()
{
    $jenjang = Yii::$app->request->get('jenjang');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM adikbinaan";

    if($jenjang!=0){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM adikbinaan WHERE adikbinaan.jenjang_id = $jenjang";
    }

    $n = count(CariAdikBinaan::findBySql($sql)->all());

    $adikbinaan = new SqlDataProvider([
        'sql' => $sql,
        'totalCount' => $n,
        'sort' => [
            'attributes' => [
                'ADIKBINAAN_NAMALENGKAP',
            ],
        ],
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 20,
        ],
    ]);

    $adik = new CariAdikBinaan();

    return $this->render('index', [
        'dataProvider' => $adikbinaan,
        'data' => $adik,
    ]);
}
```

My View

```php
    <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'layout'=>"{pager}\n{items}\n{summary}",
    'showFooter'=>true,
    'showHeader'=>true,
    'showOnEmpty'=>false,
    'columns' => [
        'ADIKBINAAN_NAMALENGKAP',
        'ADIKBINAAN_TEMPATLAHIR',
        'ADIKBINAAN_TANGGALLAHIR',
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

When i click *View* or *Update* Button from Action Column, the URL returns `view?id=0` or `update?id=0` not `id` from database.

How do i fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to declare which column is the identifying column in your SqlDataProvider. Otherwise you just get that serial number. So put the [key](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-sqldataprovider.html#$key-detail) attribute to the provider:

```php
$adikbinaan = new SqlDataProvider([
    'sql'        => $sql,
    'totalCount' => $n,
    'key'        => 'id'  // <---- here it is, can also be an array of strings if more columns are identifiying ones
    'sort'       => [
        'attributes' => [
            'ADIKBINAAN_NAMALENGKAP',
        ],
    ],
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 20,
    ],
]);
```

Does that work for you? I suppose my other answer is less valuable...

Btw: This

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM adikbinaan WHERE adikbinaan.jenjang_id = $jenjang";
```

is dangerous since SQL injection would work. Also the way how you count the records in efficient. Look at the example of the class [SqlDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-sqldataprovider.html). There `COUNT(*)` is used which requires quite less data transfer.

Answer (score 0):

[ActionColumn](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-actioncolumn.html) creates the URL by default with method [createUrl()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-actioncolumn.html#createUrl%28%29-detail). You could override this with declaring an alternative implementation:

```php
'columns' => [
    'ADIKBINAAN_NAMALENGKAP',
    'ADIKBINAAN_TEMPATLAHIR',
    'ADIKBINAAN_TANGGALLAHIR',
    [
        'class'      => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn', 
        'urlCreator' => function($action, $model, $key, $index) {
            return Url::to([
                'someController/' . $action, 
                // not sure: either this
                'id' => $model->fieldThatContainsId,
                // or this:
                'id' => $model['fieldThatContainsId'],
            ]);
        }
    ],
],
```

I'm posting that without really knowing if it's possible. I haven't tried it. Usually, ActionColumn is used with ActiveRecord instances that you get when you use ActiveDataProvider. If you have such ActiveRecord model instances you could also that provider as an alternative.